# Several console instanses in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

Is there a simple way to create several console instances(windows) in Node.js to stream there logs?

I imagine such code:

```
var consoles = require('consoles')

console1 = consoles.createConsole({name:"name1", title:"some title1"})
console1.log("Hello console 1!")

console2 = consoles.createConsole({name:"name2", title:"some title2"})
console2.log("Hello console 2!")
```

Which creates two console windows with corresponding records.

Upd: I played with different logging packages looking this feature : [debug](https://www.npmjs.org/package/debug), [log](https://www.npmjs.org/package/log), [winston](https://www.npmjs.org/package/winston), [bunyan](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bunyan)

They all solve task of logging, and maybe I can use them. For example, I could write specific transport for winston, or stream for bunyan....
But my question is - how to make several instanses/windows of console/tty/terminal and get their stdin streams?

Answer (score -2):

Console.log is a bad way to log events. There are multiple modules for logging which enable you to filter output and choose where the output goes. Have a look at [debug](https://www.npmjs.org/package/debug), [log](https://www.npmjs.org/package/log) and many others.